# pandas: fill nans given a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with something that seemed to be trivial but apparently isn't. General picture: `data` - pandas dataframe - contains(among others) `TOTAL_VISITS` and `NUM_PRINTS` columns.

Objective: given `num_prints` parameter, find rows where `NUM_prints = num_prints` and fill `nan`s with a given number.

Where I stopped and it didn't make sense anymore:

```
indices= data['NUM_PRINTS'] == num_prints

data.loc[indices,'TOTAL_VISITS'].fillna(5,inplace=True)
```

This should work as much as I know and read. didn't fill nans with anything in practice, seemed like it worked with a copy or something as it didn't change anything in the original object.

What works:

```
data.loc[indices,'TOTAL_VISITS'] = 2
```

this does fill the column with 2's on the `num_print` condition, but does not consider nans.

```
data['TOTAL_VISITS'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

this does fill the nans in total visits with 0, but does not consider the `num_prints` condition.

I'm kinda hopeless as a regular `for` loop with `.iloc` and conditions takes way too long than I can handle.

Answer (score 3):

I think this one works fine

```
data['TOTAL_VISITS'] = np.where(data['NUM_PRINTS'] == 1, 100, data['TOTAL_VISITS'])
```

Comment: simple, clean, elegant.  I think np.where is massively under-rated

Answer (score 2):

I think need filter in both sides and apply `fillna` only for filtered rows:

```
np.random.seed(1213)

c = ['TOTAL_VISITS', 'A', 'NUM_PRINTS']
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,np.nan,3,4], size=(10,3)), columns=c)
print (data)
   TOTAL_VISITS    A  NUM_PRINTS
0           1.0  4.0         4.0
1           NaN  3.0         1.0
2           1.0  1.0         1.0
3           4.0  3.0         3.0
4           1.0  3.0         4.0
5           4.0  4.0         3.0
6           4.0  1.0         4.0
7           NaN  4.0         3.0
8           NaN  NaN         3.0
9           3.0  NaN         1.0


num_prints = 1
indices= data['NUM_PRINTS'] == num_prints
data.loc[indices,'TOTAL_VISITS'] = data.loc[indices,'TOTAL_VISITS'].fillna(100)
#alternative
#data.loc[indices,'TOTAL_VISITS'] = data['TOTAL_VISITS'].fillna(100)
print (data)
   TOTAL_VISITS    A  NUM_PRINTS
0           1.0  4.0         4.0
1         100.0  3.0         1.0
2           1.0  1.0         1.0
3           4.0  3.0         3.0
4           1.0  3.0         4.0
5           4.0  4.0         3.0
6           4.0  1.0         4.0
7           NaN  4.0         3.0
8           NaN  NaN         3.0
9           3.0  NaN         1.0
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick response
it would be better to print (data) before the change so we can confirm it's validity, but either way it didn't work for me
https://pastebin.com/X01VzBax
I commented the prints

Comment: @user9548409 - there is somrthing very wrong, because after fillna is not possible more missing values. Can you test only one column before and after applying solution? `print(data['TOTAL_VISITS'].isnull().sum())` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to apply your logic, without using `fillna` is to define a mask including your criteria. Then update a series via `.loc` using this mask.

The below example works with data from @jezrael.

```
num_prints = 1

mask = (data['NUM_PRINTS'] == num_prints) & data['TOTAL_VISITS'].isnull()

data.loc[mask, 'TOTAL_VISITS'] = 100
```